# overloading shift left and shift right operator (cin and cout)

Tags: c++

I've already made a Point class [here](http://cpp.sh/75b). Everything works fine when I write

```
cout << p1 << endl; //which p is a Point
```

but when I have two objects of Point and write

```
cout << (p1 + p2) << endl; //or (p1 - p2) and etc...
```

i get errors. You can see the errors here. I don't know the reason. please help.

Comment: Please add whether `p1+p2` isoltatedly works. If it doesn't, then re-write your question to contain the minimum code necessary to produce the error. Also, you forgot to add the error. Add it directly to your question, it's most likely crucial to the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't see the errors here. Please add them (in text), **after**  searching for the error. This question may very well be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you are attempting to pass an rvalue into a function which accepts a non-const lvalue reference. This is [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object). To fix the issue, just take the `Point` argument by const reference:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Point &p);
```

Answer (score 3):

The error should come from the output operator signature: instead of having:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Point &p){
    output << '(' << p._x << ", " << p._y << ')';
    return output;
}
```

you should have:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Point &p) { // notice const here
    output << '(' << p._x << ", " << p._y << ')';
    return output;
}
```

This is because `(p1 + p2)` returns a temporary and that needs to bind to a **const** reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://cpp.sh/5aig) is corrected code

You need to add `const` specifier, like this

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream&, const Point&);
```

It's offtopic, but your input is would not work with output, since you read two doubles separated by space, but output it parentheses and comma.

Comment: The input operator cannot input into a const reference. Only the output operator should be changed.